# Check if auto sync is enabled in Android

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to put a button to enable or disable the auto sync, I know there's a way to enable the auto sync to all accounts with `ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(boolean)`, but I can't find a way to check if this "Master Sync" is enabled. Is there any way to find it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getMasterSyncAutomatically()